# Data is not populated in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ui-grid for creating a grid. I want to display a dropdown in one of the column of it, so using cell template for it.

```
 var subGridCols = [{
        name: "cpu",
        displayName: "CPU"

    }, {
        name: "memory",
        displayName: "Memory"

    }, {
        name: "storage",
        displayName: "Storage"

    },  {
        name: "recovery_point",
        displayName: "Recovery Point",
        cellTemplate: "<div><select data-ng-model='correctlySelected' data-ng-options = 'point for point in recovery_points' ></select></div>"
    }];
```

Initially the dropdown list will be empty.But after clicking start button ajax call will retrieve the data and will populate it in dropdown.

```
 $scope.start = function(row) {

    $http.get("recovery_point.json").then(function(data) {

         $scope.recovery_points = data.data.recovery_points.history_array;

         console.log($scope.recovery_points);

    });
};
```

The data is present in the scope of the grid but it is not reflected in the dropdown. Please guide me where i am going wrong.

link for the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/NDId51mnoIzM34LQZboY?p=preview

Comment: you are not calling     $scope.start  method..

Comment: first you need to init your model 'correctlySelected' and then call to $scope.start method

Comment: @Ved : I am calling $scope.start method on the click of start button.

Comment: since you are initializing your dropDoen with $scope.recovery_points, inside $scope.start method. it should be initialized at the load event. otherwise you will get empty deopdown.

Comment: Thats correct. But how to populate values of dropdown dynamically as here i will get the values after the ajax call.